# How to change `JTextArea` contents using `JTextArea` instance field?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have an object `ReminderGUI` which has a `JTextArea` field. `ReminderGUI` represents an app which lets save and display reminders. When `getReminderButton` is clicked I want the app to find the reminder which was previously saved for this date and display it in the `JTextArea` (I'm not showing this functionality in the code snippet).

I'm having trouble with changing `JTextArea` text and the code below demonstrates it. Once `getReminderButton` is clicked then `getReminderButtonHandler()` is supposed to initialize a new  blank `JTextArea` and then append it to `some new text here`. Why doesn't this work?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ReminderGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JButton getReminderButton;
    private JTextArea reminderTextArea;

    public ReminderGUI() {
        super();
        super.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.reminderTextArea = new JTextArea("Enter text");
        this.getReminderButton = new JButton("Get reminder");

        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();

        southPanel.add(getReminderButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        super.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        super.add(reminderTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.getReminderButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == this.getReminderButton) {
            this.getReminderButtonHandler();
        }
    }

    private void getReminderButtonHandler() {
        this.reminderTextArea = new JTextArea("");
        this.reminderTextArea.append("some new text here");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReminderGUI rmg = new ReminderGUI();
        rmg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        rmg.setSize(500, 300);
        rmg.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nehorai this solved the issue but why was my method incorrect?

Comment: You're creating a ***new*** JTextArea in the method, why should it work? If you set the text of this new JTextArea, why do you think it would magically change the text in the displayed JTextArea? This suggests a basic misunderstanding about how Java objects work.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels but I'm setting it to the existing field. Do I need to use some kind of `repaint()` method?

Comment: No. Please read the edit to my comment. Again this suggests that you're confused about how Java objects work. A new JTextArea is a completely different object.

Comment: Get rid of `this.reminderTextArea = new JTextArea("");` in  your method.

Comment: Note that `"but I'm setting it to the existing field"` is true, but this has no effect on the ***displayed*** object which is the original object, which is the one whose text you wish to change.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels now I understand this. But is there some method that can "reload" the app in order to display any such changes?

Comment: The changes should be displayed ***without*** having to reload anything. Simply calling `setText(...)` or `append(...)` on the existing JTextArea is **all** that is required.  I'm guessing that something else may be confusing you, perhaps in code you're not showing us.

Comment: What do you want this GUI to do that it's currently **not** doing?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it makes perfect sense that it's enough to use `setText()`, I just thought that just like `repaint()` can refresh the look of an app that maybe there were some similar method for my case.

Comment: If you call `setText(...)` rather than `append(...)` then all existing text is erased.

Comment: Swing components are built on a modified model-view-controller structure. When you change the model here by calling `.append(...)` or `setText(...)` the model *notifies* the view of this change, and a repaint is automatically called, so there's no need for you to do this. The exception to this is if you do custom painting such as within a paintComponent method. Then you the coder are responsible for calling `repaint()`. Also you need to do this if you add or remove components as a program is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line: `this.reminderTextArea = new JTextArea("Enter text");` you're creating a new TextArea

You can set it using the `set` method, like this: `reminderTextArea.setText(text);`